# std::any for move-only template where static_assert inside copy-ctor equals compile error, but why?

Tags: c++, stdany

I don't see why move-only templates can not be extended by copy-ctor having a `static_assert` (like in the code below) in order to be used with `std::any`

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <cassert>

namespace detail{
template<typename T=int>
struct MoveOnly
{
    MoveOnly() = default;
    MoveOnly(MoveOnly const&) {static_assert(sizeof(T)!=sizeof(T),"");}
    MoveOnly(MoveOnly &&) = default;
    MoveOnly &operator=(MoveOnly const&) {static_assert(sizeof(T)!=sizeof(T),"");}
    MoveOnly &operator=(MoveOnly &&) = default;
};
}
using MoveOnly = detail::MoveOnly<>;
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<MoveOnly>::value,"");

int main() {
    MoveOnly a;
    //std::any any(std::move(a)); //<- compile error
    return 0;
}
```

In [std::any::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any) it says for ctor #4

> This overload only participates in overload resolution if ... std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>> is true.

As far as I can see `std::is_copy_constructible<MoveOnly>::value` gives true and copy-ctor is never being called. So how is it possible that the compiler still complains about the `static_assert` inside copy-ctor?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I would imagine that `std::any` is very much like `std::function` in that since it needs to go through polymorphism to be implemented, it has no choice but to require copy-constructibility of its assigned content.

Comment: @Frank I understand that and they check it with `std::is_copy_constructible<MoveOnly>::value` right? So I managed to get that value to true, so i don't see how they can still figure out the `static_assert` in the end without actually calling copy-ctor directly.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  ctor #4 is going to be picked because `std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>>` is `true`.  That means you make a copy, which means your `static_assert` fires.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica No as far as I can see #4 is only enabled if `std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>>` is `true`. But it still uses move-ctor if you use `std::move`

Comment: `std::move` doesn't move anything.  All it does is cast the object to an rvalue reference.  ctor #4 is always going to make a copy, that's why it requires `is_copy_constructible`.  If it could move or copy, it would just require `is_move_constructible`.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Change `static_assert` to `assert` in the code above and see it yourself. The move casts to rvalue ref. and therefore it uses move-ctor.

Comment: The function gets created anyways because it gets pointed at by a helper type's vtable. That's because the `std::any` could get copied into another `std::any` in some other translation unit. The copy constructor is not called in YOUR code, but it might be called from somewhere else. There's no way to tell ahead of time.

Comment: Ok. So do I understand this correct: The copy-ctor gets created and static_assert is being fired because a simple pointer is pointing to the copy-ctor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following case:

foo.h:

```
void foo(const std::any& v);
```

foo.cpp:

```
void foo(const std::any& v) {
  std::any tmp = v;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    MoveOnly a;
    std::any any(std::move(a));

    foo(any);

    return 0;
}
```

Inside of `main.cpp`, there is no way of knowing whether `foo()` will make a copy of `v` or not, so we have no choice, there **has** to be a copy-constructor available *just in case* it might need to be invoked.

**edit:** To address something mentioned in the comments:

> Ok. So do I understand this correct: The copy-ctor gets created and static_assert is being fired because a simple pointer is pointing to the copy-ctor?

In essence, yes. As soon as a pointer refers to a function, that function has to exist, and bringing that function into existence will trigger code-gen for it, including evaluating any `static_assert()` within.

The only thing that's a little off in your understanding is that the pointer doesn't exist just for the heck of it. It's there because there's a real possibility that it might be used to invoke the pointed function. Maybe it will get optimized away during LTO, but that's too late; code-gen is finished by then